# wget does not download all the files, and links aren't converted

Tags: wget

I tried

```
wget -pk http://www.bbc.com/news/
```

to download this news site and store a local copy.

`-p` is used to save all the files in order to view the website locally. `-k` converts the links so that they should point to the local file.

But when I open the local HTML file of that website, and I do a right click on the displayed images... the image file on [www.bbc.com](http://www.bbc.com) is opened.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

the coorect command is `wget -r -k -np http://bbc.com/news`

1. r   for recursive
2. k   for convert link after download
3. np  for no parent

Answer (score -2):

You need to add few options to -p, use this command :

```
wget -E -H -k -K -p http://bbc.com/news
```

Comment: Can you please explain what are the arguments passed to wget?

Comment: Find out here : http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html